# Subharmonic functions in the punctured disk

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, harmonic-functions

I want to prove the following (exercise from Ahlfors' text):

> If $\Omega$ is the punctured disk $0<|z|<1$ and if $f$ is given by $f(\zeta)=0$ for $|\zeta|=1$, $f(0)=1$, show that all functions $v \in \mathfrak B(f)$ are $\leq0$ in $\Omega$.

Here $\mathfrak B(f)$ is the class of all functions $v$ which satisfy:

(a) $v$ is subharmonic in $\Omega$.

(b) $\limsup_{z \to \zeta} v(z) \leq f(\zeta)$ for all $\zeta \in \partial \Omega$.

After quite some time with no success, a short google search gave me [this](http://books.google.co.il/books?id=beSXZhrfDngC&pg=PA405&lpg=PA405&dq=subharmonic%20punctured%20disk&source=bl&ots=cyEFCmwhRu&sig=Nuq-LJIySnOVz8tV4HdtOTkG9Sw&hl=en&sa=X&ei=4FtuUrayGcGstAb654DQCA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=subharmonic%20punctured%20disk&f=false) , which has some hints, but I need to get the full book in order to understand the references.

Any help on solving this problem will be highly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given an arbitrary $v \in \mathfrak{B}(f)$, consider the functions

$$u_\varepsilon(z) = v(z) + \varepsilon\cdot \log \lvert z\rvert$$

for $\varepsilon > 0$. Since $\log \lvert z\rvert$ is harmonic in the punctured disk, $u_\varepsilon$ is subharmonic. Since $\limsup\limits_{z\to 0} v(z) < \infty$, we have $\lim\limits_{z\to 0} u_\varepsilon(z) = -\infty$. Also, $\log \lvert z\rvert \equiv 0$ on the unit circle.

By the maximum principle<sup>(1)</sup>, $u_\varepsilon \leqslant 0$ in the punctured disk. Let $\varepsilon \to 0$.

<sup>(1)</sup> If we had $u_\varepsilon(z_0) = c > 0$ for some $z_0 \in \Omega$, then $u_\varepsilon$ would attain a global maximum in $\Omega$, hence be constant ($\equiv -\infty$):

Since $\limsup_{z\to \zeta} \leqslant 0$ for all $\zeta\in \partial \Omega$, each $\zeta\in\partial\Omega$ has an open neighbourhood $U_\zeta$ with $u_\varepsilon \leqslant c/2$ on $U_\zeta$.

$$K = \Omega \setminus \bigcup_{\zeta\in\partial\Omega} U_\zeta$$

is then a compact subset of $\Omega$ containing $z_0$, in particular non-empty. The upper semicontinuous (or even continuous) function $u_\varepsilon\lvert_K$ attains its maximum in $K$, say at $z_1$. Then $u_\varepsilon$ attains its global maximum in $\Omega$ in the point $z_1$.

Comment: Could you please elaborate about the maximum principle part? I don't think $u_\varepsilon$ can be extended continuously to the boundary.

Comment: $u_\varepsilon$ can be extended continuously to the $\lvert z\rvert = 1$ part of the boundary iff $v$ can. But we don't need a continuous extension to the boundary. If we had $u_\varepsilon (z_0) > 0$ for some $z_0$, $u_\varepsilon$ would have to have a (global and) local maximum in $\Omega$. That would imply it is constant in $\delta < \lvert z\rvert < \rho$ for all sufficiently small $\delta > 0$ and sufficiently large $\rho <1$.

Comment: If I may ask, why would having a positive value force $u_\varepsilon$ to have a local maximum?

Comment: Because the boundary values (take $\limsup$) are non-positive. So if $u_\varepsilon(z_0) = c > 0$, we can find a neighbourhood $N$ of the (compact) boundary with $u_\varepsilon(z) \leqslant c/2$ on $N$. Ahlfors treats only continuous subharmonic functions iirc, but even with upper semicontinuous functions, $u_\varepsilon$ attains its maximum in the compact set $K = \overline{\Omega \setminus N} \subset \Omega$. By choice of $N$, that is a global maximum in $\Omega$.